# Selecting columns from a table based on a previous query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to utilize the new [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#column_field_paths_view) metadata table to dynamically build queries on the fly, something akin to doing reflection. What I want to be able to do is filter out columns that match a certain keyword in the column's description.

Here's an attempt at what I'm trying to do:

```sql
WITH
  nonconfidential_mytable_columns AS (
  SELECT
    column_name
  FROM
    `mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
  WHERE
    table_name = "mytable"
    AND description NOT LIKE "%CONFIDENTIAL%")
SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    nonconfidential_mytable_columns)
FROM
  `mydataset.mytable`
```

This is not functional but hopefully gets the desire across: I want to select columns from a table based on the result of another query. I could do this easily with multiple queries, but I want to save this as a view.

Comment: You'll probably need to do this from outside BigQuery - let's say, a cloud function for example that calls bigquery and creates new views

Comment: There is no a column called 'description' in information_schema...

Comment: @kenean, please take a second look, if you 
```sql
select * from `dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
```
 you'll see that there is a description column. It's also shown in the documentation that I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Below (for BigQuery Standard SQL) is the closest to your case that I got to

```
#standardSQL
WITH nonconfidential_mytable_columns AS (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(column_name) cols
    FROM `mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
    WHERE table_name = 'mytable'
    AND description NOT LIKE "%CONFIDENTIAL%"
)
SELECT 
    IF('col1' IN UNNEST(cols), col1, NULL) col1,
    IF('col2' IN UNNEST(cols), col2, NULL) col2,
    IF('col3' IN UNNEST(cols), col3, NULL) col3
FROM `mydataset.mytable`, nonconfidential_mytable_columns
```

I think, it is close enough - but still not exactly what your "requirements" are - because still all column names are exposed, but the values for "confidential" columns are all NULLs now. And also - you need to explicitly list all columns vs. using `*`

Anyway - now you can save above as a view, but it is very important to not to save it in the same dataset as `mydataset` but rather to save it in dataset (let's say `users_dataset`) that is freely available to users and then share `mydataset` with the view via `Authorized View` option